# Find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate

Tags: python, predicate

I want an idiomatic way to find the first element in a list that matches a predicate.

The current code is quite ugly:

```
[x for x in seq if predicate(x)][0]
```

I've thought about changing it to:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
dropwhile(lambda x: not predicate(x), seq).next()
```

But there must be something more elegant... And it would be nice if it returns a `None` value rather than raise an exception if no match is found.

I know I could just define a function like:

```
def get_first(predicate, seq):
    for i in seq:
        if predicate(i): return i
    return None
```

But it is quite tasteless to start filling the code with utility functions like this (and people will probably not notice that they are already there, so they tend to be repeated over time) if there are built ins that already provide the same.

Comment: Besides being asked later than "[python sequence find function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039425/python-sequence-find-function)", this question has a **much better title**.

Answer (score 456, accepted):

To find the first element in a sequence `seq` that matches a `predicate`:

```
next(x for x in seq if predicate(x))
```

Or simply:

**Python 2**:

```
next(itertools.ifilter(predicate, seq))
```

**Python 3**:

```
next(filter(predicate, seq))
```

These will raise a `StopIteration` exception if the predicate does not match for any element.

---

To return `None` if there is no such element:

```
next((x for x in seq if predicate(x)), None)
```

Or:

```
next(filter(predicate, seq), None)
```

Comment: Or you can supply a second "default" argument to `next` that is used instead of raising the exception.

Comment: @fortran: [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) is available since Python 2.6 You could read [What's New page](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html) to quickly familiarize yourself with new features.

Comment: I am a python newbie and read the docs and the ifilter uses the "yield" method. I assume this means that the predicate is lazily evaluated as we go. i.e, we dont run the predicate through the entire list because I have a predicate function that is a bit expensive and I want to only iterate till the point where we find an item

Comment: @CalmStorm: yes. It iterates only until the item is found.

Comment: The fact that one variant uses `ifilter` and the other one does not is not helping. Please consider using generator expression in both for clarity.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: I did it intentionally. If a predicate is a named function then `ifilter()` code contains less moving parts (better) and if the predicate is just a one-time expression then the genexpr is more suitable. So I've shown both variants. You're right: it's less clear because the two are not exactly equivalent, so it creates some confusion if a person doesn't know [what `ifilter()` does](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter). Those that don't want to be forced to learn can read [the very next answer by @Chewie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534391/4279).

Comment: This is a bad solution as it continues searching even after it finds a match.

Comment: @Charlie: it does *not*

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian based on the docs, the list comprehension returns a list. From what I can read, there's no indication this list is lazily populated as the iterator progresses.

Comment: @Charlie: that is why the solution uses genexpr, not listcomp

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I see now, I wasn't aware of generator expressions. For Anyone else looking for more info: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Comment: ...and that's where I love ruby `seq.find {|x| predicate(x)}`.

Comment: @geekazoid: `seq.find(&method(:predicate))` or even more concise for instance methods e.g.: `[1,1,4].find(&:even?)`

Comment: `ifilter` was renamed to `filter` in Python 3.

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Sometimes, in Python, it can be hard to figure out how to accomplish these things.

Answer (score 106):

You could use a generator expression with a default value and then `next` it:

```
next((x for x in seq if predicate(x)), None)
```

Although for this one-liner you need to be using Python >= 2.6.

This rather popular article further discusses this issue: [Cleanest Python find-in-list function?](http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function).

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there's anything wrong with either solutions you proposed in your question.

In my own code, I would implement it like this though:

```
(x for x in seq if predicate(x)).next()
```

The syntax with `()` creates a generator, which is more efficient than generating all the list at once with `[]`.

Comment: And not only that - with `[]` you might run into problems if the iterator never ends or its elements are hard to create, the later it gets...

Comment: `'generator' object has no attribute 'next'` on Python 3.

Comment: @glglgl - As for the first point (never ends) I doubt it, as the argument is a finite sequence [more precisely a list according to the OP' question]. As for the second: again, since the argument supplied is a sequence, the objects should have already been created and stored by the time this function is called.... or am I missing something?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Thank you, I wasn't aware of that! :) Out of curiosity, what's the design principle behind this choice?

Comment: @mac - For consistency with the double underscore of other special methods. See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/

Comment: @mac For the given case you are right - but in the general case where those restrictions are not present, problems can occur.

Answer (score 5):

J.F. Sebastian's answer is most elegant but requires python 2.6 as fortran pointed out.

For Python version < 2.6, here's the best I can come up with:

```
from itertools import repeat,ifilter,chain
chain(ifilter(predicate,seq),repeat(None)).next()
```

Alternatively if you needed a list later (list handles the StopIteration), or you needed more than just the first but still not all, you can do it with islice:

```
from itertools import islice,ifilter
list(islice(ifilter(predicate,seq),1))
```

UPDATE:
Although I am personally using a predefined function called first() that catches a StopIteration and returns None, Here's a possible improvement over the above example: avoid using filter / ifilter:

```
from itertools import islice,chain
chain((x for x in seq if predicate(x)),repeat(None)).next()
```

Comment: Yikes!  if it comes down to that, I would just do the simple "for" loop with an "if" inside it -- much easier to read