# How to find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/python-find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate)

Is there a higher order function in Python standard library that encapsulates the following control flow pattern?

```
>>> def find(pred, coll):
...   for x in coll:
...     if pred(x):
...       return x
... 
>>> find(lambda n : n % 2 == 0, [3, 5, 8, 9, 6])
8
>>> find(lambda n : n % 2 == 0, [3, 5, 7, 9, 6])
6
>>> find(lambda n : n % 2 == 0, [3, 5, 7, 9, 1])
```

Comment: All of the answers were helpful to me, but since @ThiefMaster answered first, I am putting the green tick on his answer. :) I have upvoted all the answers. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine `ifilter` and `islice` to get just the first matching element.

```
>>> list(itertools.islice(itertools.ifilter(lambda n: n % 2 == 0, lst), 1))
[8]
```

However, I wouldn't consider this anyhow more readable or nicer than the original code you posted. Wrapped in a function it will be much nicer though. And since [`next`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) only returns one element there is no need for `islice` anymore:

```
def find(pred, iterable):
    return next(itertools.ifilter(pred, iterable), None)
```

It returns `None` if no element was found.

However, you still have the rather slow call of the predicate function every loop. Please consider using a list comprehension or generator expression instead:

```
>>> next((x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0), None)
8
```

Comment: +1 itertools and comprehension is the most idiomatic way to do functional programming-style in my opinion :)

Comment: That's `filter`. I am looking for `find`. (i.e. a HOF that returns the first element that satisfies the predicate.)

Answer (score 4):

[`itertools.ifilter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) can do this, if you just grab the first element of the resulting iterable.

```
itertools.ifilter(pred, col1).next()
```

Similarly, so could a generator object (again, taking the first item out of the resulting generator):

```
(i for i in col1 if i % 2 == 0).next()
```

Since both of these are lazy-evaluated, you'll only evaluate as much of the input iterable as is necessary to get to the first element that satisfies the predicate. Note that if nothing matches the predicate, you'll get a `StopIteration` exception. You can avoid this by using the `next()` builtin instead:

```
next((i for i in col1 if i % 2 == 0), None)
```

Comment: I hope this doesn't compute the whole collection prematurely? I need only the first element that meets the criterion.

Comment: See the note I just edited in as you were writing your comment - both of the methods I mentioned are lazily evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of such a function off the top of my head, but you could just use a generator expression and take the first result.

```
x = (x for x in [3,5,8,9,6] if (lambda n: n % 2 == 0)(x))
y = x.next()
```

Or just

```
y = (x for x in [3,5,8,9,6] if (lambda n: n % 2 == 0)(x)).next()
```

Comment: I think those will raise in case of no elements found

Comment: Yes, this will raise StopIteration if nothing is found.

Answer (score 2):

```
(x for x in coll if pred(x)).next()
```

Raises `StopIteration` if the item isn't found (which might be preferable to returning `None`, especially if `None` is a valid return value).