# Python converting nested loops to simple line

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7.x I have two lists I would like a function that returns the first value (not index) as shown below

```
def first_incorrect_term(polynomial, terms):
    for index in range(len(polynomial), len(terms)):
        if evaluate(polynomial, index) != terms[index-1]:
            return evaluate(polynomial, index)
```

Let us assume evaluate is a function that works. I would like to replace these three lines which looks Object Oriented into something that uses the "find" or some such function in Python.

Basically I am iterating through the indices of the second list beyond the number terms in the polynomial (as I am confident the first X terms will match), evaluating it and comparing with the expected terms. For the first instance where the terms do not match I would like the evaluated polynomial returned.

I am looking for a replacement of these 3 lines using a Python find/lambda or some such thing, this is because I can definitely see I am not using the Python power as described for example in the [link](http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function)

PS: This is somewhat related to a Project Euler problem, however I have solved it using the snippet above and would like to improve my "Python" skills :)

Comment: `for index in range(len(polynomial), len(terms))` will not iterate over the indices of polynomial, but over the indices of terms beyond the end of polynomial (poly is 5 elements, terms is 7 elements gives `range(5,7) = [5,6]`); that doesn't mesh with your description of 'iterating through the indices of the first list'.

Comment: Regarding what you actually want; are you looking for something you can iterate over?

Comment: You are right let me edit it

Comment: I am looking for a "functional" replacement of this Object Oriented like code that uses the python power !

Comment: There are no apparent objects here, nor methods being called, so it is already 'functional' to some degree... can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @PhilH What I actually meant was I seem to be instructing iterations, evaluations, comparisons which is what you would do in Java/C etc. If you look at the link http://tomayko.com/writings/cleanest-python-find-in-list-function something similar to that is what I am after. Hope tha tmakes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, use `yield` to make a generator version of your function:

```
def incorrect_terms(polynomial, terms):
    for index in range(len(polynomial), len(terms)):
        eval = evaluate(polynomial,index)
        if eval != terms[index-1]:
            yield (polynomial, index, eval)
```

Then the first result is the first mismatch:

```
mismatches = incorrect_terms(polynomial, terms)
first_mismatch = mismatches.next()
```

I think you actually want to iterate over all the values of terms, not the values after polynomial's length, in which case you can zip:

```
results = (evaluate(polynomial,index) for index in count(0))
pairsToCompare = itertools.izip(results, terms)
mismatches = (pair for pair in pairsToCompare if pair[0] != pair[1])

first_mismatch = mismatches.next()
```

Assuming here that `evaluate(polynomial, n)` is calculating the nth term for a given polynomial, and that these are being compared with the values in `terms`.

Comment: Phil I definitely want to evaluate from a point and not zero as evaluating is not a trivial function and is somewhat expensive. Also I don't want to compute all evaluations because as N increases the time taken to evaluate increases. So I would prefer stopping at the earliest available oppurtunity

Comment: @CalmStorm: All the approaches shown here are lazily evaluated, that is they only evaluate the values one at a time -- izip doesn't evaluate the next thing for the zip until it is asked for. Regarding evaluation from zero or not: I can only guess at the `evaluate` function; it seemed plausible that you are evaluating the terms in a polynomial and comparing them. In that case, I expected you to need to compare all the terms, from the first, but stopping when you find a discrepancy. If that is not the case, go with the first version.

Comment: The question is very useful as well in this context http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/python-find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using generator expressions, but they don't fit in one line as well:

```
def first_incorrect_term(polynomial, terms):
    evaled = ((index, evaluate(polynomial, index)) for index in range(len(polynomial), len(terms)))
    return next((val for index, val in evaled if val != terms[index-1]), None)
```