# Find element in list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like

```
list_a = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
```

and now using this list i wanted to find a element which has last value 3 any short method to achieve this? it should return `(2,3)`

Comment: What do you expect the return value to be?

Comment: @user1182043 what if there are multiple such pairs?

Comment: related: [Python: find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/python-find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example:

```
In [1]: list_a = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 5)]

In [2]: next(x for x in list_a if x[1] == 3)
Out[2]: (2, 3)
```

Note that it returns a single element, not a list of them (seems to be what you are asking). If there are multiple tuples, the first one is returned.

Comment: Use `next((...), None)` so that it doesn't raise an exception when the values run out.

Comment: @Volatility Thanks for the comment. I'll leave it for the OP to decide; having an exception in this case may be also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in list_a:
    if item[-1] == 3:
        return item
```

Or, if you might want to return multiple values:

```
return_list = []
for item in list_a:
    if item[-1] == 3:
        return_list.append(item)
return return_list
```

Comment: You might wanna use non-capitalized `for`.

Comment: Ha! Hadn't seen that, thanks. The list comprehension answers are way better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

something simple like

```
for x in list_a: 
    if x[1] == 3: print x
```