# In Python, how do I find the index of an sub-item given a list?

Tags: python, list

Given the list:

```
li = ['a', 'b', 'new', 'mpilgrim', 'z', 'example', 'new', 'two', 'elements']
```

How do I find the (first) index containing the string `amp`? Note that `amp` is contained the word `example`.

FYI, this works: `li.index("example")`

But this does not: `li.index("amp")`

Comment: related: [Python: find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8534256/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a generator expression with [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> next((i for i,x in enumerate(li) if 'amp' in x), None)
5
```

This will return `None` if no such item was found.