# Search in python tuple list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

```
db = [('cat',15,22),('dog',28,30),('human',27,80)]
```

Now I want to create search for 'dog' so my returned value will be `db[1]`. I can't still figure it out (I know I would use sth like `for item in db: if 'dog' in item[:]` but don't know how to put it together really.

Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = [i for i in db if 'dog' in i]
items[0] if items else None
# ('dog', 28, 30)
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the tuple into a list to use `in`.
`[i for i in db if 'dog' in i]` would work as well.

Comment: Also, @user3056783 wants his returned value to be `db[1]` so this should be `[i for i in db if 'do' in i][0]`; this of course would blow up with an `IndexError: list index out of range` if 'dog' was not found (as the list you constructed would be empty).

Comment: I added the code to safely check for an empty result.

Comment: Yes I like this one and sort of understand it. If i were to look more into it, what is this kind of coding called: `[i for i in db if 'dog' in i]` ? Just so I know what to search for.

Comment: @user3056783 it's called a "list comprehension"; there's also a similarly looking syntax for generators (I'd recommend reading about those as well as they're pretty ubiquitous in python): `(i for i in db if 'dog' in i)` (this is what I'm using in my answer)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the first item that matches (as suggested by you saying that your returned value should be `db[1]`) then you can use

```
next((x for x in db if x[0] == 'dog'), None)
```

In case `'dog'` may be in any element of the tuple - so that `(28, 'dog', 30)` would also be matched - I'd go with

```
next((x for x in db if 'dog' in x), None)
```

See the answers to [find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/python-find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate) for how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter:

```
filter(lambda x:'dog' in x, db)
```

Output:

```
[('dog', 28, 30)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?

```
f = lambda db,x: [_t for _t in db if _t[0]==x][0]
```

Output:

```
>>> f(db,'dog')
('dog', 28, 30)
```