# Python - choose a single element with some property from an array

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I have come across this case a few times now: I have an array which contains an element I want and I want to select that element without knowing the index, and instead knowing some desired property (maybe it is a list of dictionaries and I want the dictionary `elem` such that `elem['foo'] == 'bar'`).

A solution I have is do a filter (or more pythonically, a list comprehension) and then take the first element (often times I know that the filtered list will be a singleton, so taking the first is taking the only).

Ex. Given a list `x = [{'foo': 'bar_1'}, {'foo': 'bar_2'}]`, I want the element whose `'foo'` value is `'bar2'`. So I do this :

```
y = [elem for elem in x if elem['foo'] == 'bar_2'][0]
```

Is there a more standard way of doing this? It seems like a very simple and common use case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/python-find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate)

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this problem frequently then consider using a different data structure. Think about whether a list of dicts is really the best data structure for the problem you are solving. Or, if it is, add a `dict` to keep track of the information you require. In this case, as you build `x`, also build `index`:

```
index = {'bar2':x[1], 'bar1':x[0]}
```

[Dict lookups are `O(1)`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), whereas any list-based lookup is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `generator`  calling `next` on it to get the first match:

```
l = [{'foo': 'bar_1'}, {'foo': 'bar_2'}]
print next(d for d in l if d["foo"] == "bar_2")
{'foo': 'bar_2'}

d = (d for d in l if d["foo"] == "bar_2")
first = next(d)
```

You could also you [itertools.dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and if you want the first two elements:

```
In [52]: from itertools import dropwhile,takewhile
In [53]: l = [{'foo': 'bar_1'}, {'foo': 'bar_2'},{'foo': 'bar_2',"goo":"bar"}]
In [54]: d = dropwhile(lambda x: x["foo"] != "bar_2",l)   # drop elements whose where value of key "foo" is not equal to "bar_2"
In [55]: first = next(d)
In [56]: second = next(d)    
In [57]: first
Out[57]: {'foo': 'bar_2'}    
In [58]: second
Out[58]: {'foo': 'bar_2', 'goo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Alternatively, `item, = (d for d in l if d["foo"] == "bar_2")` will assert that there is only one item in the list with the given property (which may, or may not be desired).

Comment: @Dunes, yes true, I am not sure if the OP wants to check if there is only one match or just get the first.