# What is the Pythonic way to get last not-None value from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code gets the last present value from an ordered list of dated values:

```
def test_get_last_value(self):
    dated_optional_values = [(datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 23), None),
                    (datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 24), 1.23),
                    (datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 25), None),
                    (datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 26), 2.34),
                    (datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 27), None),
                    ]
    present_values = [dated_optional_value[1] for dated_optional_value in dated_optional_values
        if dated_optional_value[1] is not None]
    last_present_value = present_values[-1]
    print('last_present_value=', last_present_value)
```

I can easily write a loop which starts at the end of the list and iterates back until it finds a value.

Is there a more Pythonic way to accomplish that?

Comment: Use `reversed()`, and [find the first non-`None` value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8534256/4279)

Comment: I don't think that `reversed()` is any better than the solution you already have. Its common and "pythonic" to filter lists into new lists.

Comment: @tdelaney: `reversed()` allows you to avoid enumerating all values unnecessarily if there is a non-`None` value near the end. In the same way like `any()`, `all()` functions have the short-circuit behavior. It doesn't matter in OPs case because the list is very short. But I don't see any indication that a very small list is expected in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
next((dop[1] for dop in reversed(date_optional_values) if dop[1] is not None), None)
```

You can replace the final `None` with whatever other value you prefer to return the case where every value is `None`. Or omit that argument to throw an exception in the case where they're all `None`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
last_present_value = next(x for x in reversed(dated_optional_values) 
                          if x[1] is not None)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be nice to factor the separate steps:

1. You want the second column (`x[1]`)

   `def column(data, index): return [x[index] for x in data]`
2. You want to filter out `None`

   `def notNone(data): return [x for x in data if x is not None]`
3. You want the last element

   `def last(data): return data[-1]`

Then your problem becomes

```
last_preset_value = last(notNone(column(data, 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also generalise this to take the `last n` non `None` values - for instance, to take the last 2 non blanks:

```
from itertools import islice

candidates = (el[1] for el in reversed(dated_optional_values) if el[1] is not None)
last_n = list(islice(candidates, 2)) or []
```

Also, if you don't have a `Sized` container, such as a list, and have some arbitrary iterable, you can use a `collections.deque` with a fixed size, eg:

```
from collections import deque

candidates = (el[1] for el in dated_optional_values if el[1] is not None)
d = deque([], 2)
d.extendleft(candidates)
matches = list(d) or []
```

Both of these options return:

```
[2.34, 1.23]
```