# How to search for the value of an element in a list of dict based on another value from the same element?

Tags: python

I have data in the form of a list of dicts, with some keys and values (the example below is for two keys/values, there could be more):

I would like to pythonically answer the question: what is `john`'s `age`?

The simple solution I am using now is to iterate though the list and check for a matching value of name. Is there a more pythonic way to achieve the same?

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'age': 10
    },
    {
        'name': 'paul',
        'age': 20
    }
]

age = -1    # in case the name is not found
for d in data:
    if d['name'] == 'john':
        age = d['age']

print(age)
```

Comment: No; unless you can rearrange to have a dictionary `{'john': 10, ...}` (then it's just `age = d.get('john', -1)`) that's as simple as you can get it. A `break` would improve the runtime, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `next()` and a generator expression.

The generator expression would be a one line equivalent to your for loop , and `next()` would get the next value from it (which when called first time is the first value).

Example -

```
next((d['age'] for d in data if d['name'].lower() == 'john'), -1)
```

The second argument to `-1` is like the default value to return in case the generator expression does not have anymore values (in this case - it means if the `name` - `john` does not exist in the list) .

---

Demo -

```
>>> data = [
...     {
...         'name': 'john',
...         'age': 10
...     },
...     {
...         'name': 'paul',
...         'age': 20
...     }
... ]
>>>
>>> next((d['age'] for d in data if d['name'].lower() == 'john'), None)
10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary with the name as key and age as value, then lookup the name:

```
age = {person['name']: person['age']
       for person in data}['john']
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is a list of comprehension

```
age = [d['age'] for d in data if d['name'] == 'john'][0]
```

Also, you can use filter on the list this way :

```
age = filter(lambda u : u['name'] == 'john', data)[0]['age']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this lookup for multiple names, it would be wise to generate a dict with name as a key -

```
new_dict = {datum['name']: data for datum in data}

new_dict['john']['age']
```

This way you can easily access it, and seems more pythonic. It might not be the performance optimum solution though, if your data set is too big to be a concern.