# Lambda expression with lists as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am trying to write an `if` statement in Python 3:

```
if n % 2 == 0:
    list.append(2)
elif n % 3 == 0:
    list.append(3)
elif n % 5 == 0:
    list.append(5)
```

Is there a more space conservative way of doing this?
I thought about using lambda expressions, but these bits of code don't seem to work.

```
if (lambda i: n % i == 0)(i in [2,3,5])
    list.append(i)
```

and

```
if (lambda i: n % i == 0)([2,3,5])
    list.append(i)
```

Is there a way to do this using lambda expressions? Or do I need a different approach? Also, if I use lambda expressions, will I be able to use the value of i for which the condition matches (like appending it to a list)?

Comment: What if a number is divisible by more than one of those?

Comment: I recommend that you first try it with traditional functions and then, once you're comfortable with that, transforming them into `lambda` one-liners (which isn't actually necessary anyway).

Comment: don't use `list` name; it overshadows the builtin `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> n = 33
>>> [i for i in (2, 3, 5) if n % i == 0]
[3]
>>> n = 10
>>> [i for i in (2, 3, 5) if n % i == 0]
[2, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the same result as `if`/`elif`/`elif` statements in the question:

```
your_list += next(([d] for d in [2, 3, 5] if n % d == 0), [])
```

Note: only the first divisor is appended to the list. See [find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8534256/4279).

Answer (score 0):

I can't do it with lambda functions but I think this approach with help u

```
list = [1,2,3] 
n = 9
[list.append(i) for i in (2,3,5) if n % i == 0]
print list
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```

and so on ..

Answer (score 0):

Like J.F. Sebastian`s answer this gives only the first divisor:

```
res_list.extend([i for i in (2, 3, 5) if n % i == 0][:1])
```

The `[:1]` takes only the first element of the list and 
gives an empty list if the list is empty (because a slice of an empty
list is always an empty list).

Now, `extend()` adds a one-element list as a single element to
your result list or nothing for a zero-element list.