# Find first non-None returned value from predicate over a sequence in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

On the surface, this might seem to be a duplicate of
[find first element in a sequence that matches a predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534256/find-first-element-in-a-sequence-that-matches-a-predicate)
but it is not.

I have a predicate function (function of one argument) that does some
processing on the argument and returns a non-None value when the
processing is said to "succeed". I want to use that function
efficiently on a list or even some iterable but I do not want to
iterate over all elements of the list or iterable, but just return the
*return value* of the predicate function when that value is not None,
and then stop executing the predicate on subsequent elements.

I was hoping there was something in
[itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) that
would do this, but they all seem hardwired to return the element of
the original items passed to the predicate, and instead I want the
returned value.

I have a solution shown below, but is overly heavy code-wise. I'm
wanting something more elegant and that does not require the `firstof`
utility function coded there.

Note: Reading the entire file into a list of lines is actually
necessary here, since I need the full contents in memory for other
processing.

I'm using Python 2 here; I do not want to switch to Python 3 at this
time but will want to avoid using syntax that is deprecated or missing
in Python 3.

```
import re


def match_timestamp(line):
    timestamp_re = r'\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+'
    m = re.search(r'^TIMESTAMP (' + timestamp_re + ')', line)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    return None


def firstof(pred, items):
    """Find result from the first call to pred of items.

    Do not continue to evaluate items (short-circuiting)."""
    for item in items:
        tmp = pred(item)
        if tmp:
            return tmp
    return None


log_file = "/tmp/myfile"
with open(log_file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print "line", line.rstrip()
    timestamp = firstof(match_timestamp, lines)
    print "** FOUND TIMESTAMP **", timestamp
```

Suppose I have `/tmp/myfile` contain:

```
some number of lines here
some number of lines here
some number of lines here
TIMESTAMP 2017-05-09 21:24:52
some number of lines here
some number of lines here
some number of lines here
```

Running the above program on it yeilds:

```
line some number of lines here
line some number of lines here
line some number of lines here
line TIMESTAMP 2017-05-09 21:24:52
line some number of lines here
line some number of lines here
line some number of lines here
** FOUND TIMESTAMP ** 2017-05-09 21:24:52
```

Comment: I can't say this is more efficient, but it is an alternative that uses an `itertools` recipe, stops on the first true occurrence, returns the timestamp.  `timestamp = match_timestamp(first_true(lines, default=None, pred=match_timestamp))`

Comment: @pylang +1 for notifying me of the `first_true` which I found to be shown in the recipe functions in Python 3 at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes but is not in Python 2 recipes at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html but it might apply to my use in Python 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import imap, ifilter

timestamp = next(line for line in imap(match_timestamp, lines) if line)
# or
timestamp = next(ifilter(None, imap(match_timestamp, lines)))
```

(I believe that's the way to do it in Python 2, in Python 3 you'd simply use `map`.)

`map` the function over your lines so you get a lazy iterator of your transformed values, then lazily get the next truthy value from it using `next` and a generator expression or `ifilter`. You can choose whether to let `next` raise a `StopIteration` error if no value is found, or give it a second argument for the default return value.

Comment: `filter` and `map` are now builtins in 2.7.

Comment: But are they lazy (generators) as well? From the documentation it didn't seem so.

Comment: Aha.  You are correct.  For generators in 2.7, you need to import from `itertools`.

Comment: Marking this as the answer.  [Karin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43906566/257924) was a close second and also works. I'm choosing this one as it is using `itertools` in essentially a one-liner and eliminates my `firstof` function.

Comment: Also the important aspect of this is a part of the docs that I missed upon first read at [itertools.ifilter](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) which states: "If predicate is None, return the items that are true" which is utilized in the second one-liner in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: You can create a generator and use it with `next` until a timestamp is found.

```
with open(log_file, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print "line", line.rstrip()
    timestamp = None
    generator = (match_timestamp(line) for line in lines)
    while timestamp is None:
        timestamp = next(generator)
    print "** FOUND TIMESTAMP **", timestamp
```

Comment: Ok. That's definitely close, but that ends up caling `match_timestamp` twice.

Comment: Actually, `match_timestamp` is called on every line.  This cannot be avoided since every line must pass the conditions of the predicate.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true. Try something like `def foo(x): print x` and run `generator = (foo(i) for i in range(10))`. You should get no print out. Now try `for i in range(5): next(generator)`. You should only see 0 through 4 printed.

Comment: Quite right.  Due to `next()`, your code isn't calling the predicate on every line.  Thank you.  Although there are still multiple calls, since every line is called up to the first non-None.  The point I meant to convey to the OP was that multiple calls cannot be avoided.

Comment: Correct. I'm not trying to avoid multiple executions of the `match_timestamp` function, just multiple explicit _expressions_ in the code that call the function when one will do. I see your edits and yes that improves things.